# How set new theme in SpaceVim?

Tags: vim

Currently I am using the follow codes to change the default theme to `onedark` theme:

```
sed -i '/^    colorscheme = /s/"gruvbox"/"onedark"/g' ~/.SpaceVim.d/init.toml
```

And adding `colorscheme` layer:

```
tee -a ~/.SpaceVim.d/init.toml << EOF

[[layers]]
name = "colorscheme"
EOF
```

Have a better way to do this?